# Add Quantity of item instead of duplicate in ListView

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

How do i add the quantity without duplicating the item?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

    price = 500;
    quantity = Double.Parse(maskedTextBox1.Text);
    total = price * quantity;

    string[] row = { form1.label1.Text, total.ToString(), quantity.ToString()};
    var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row);
    form1.listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);

}
```

Comment: I think it's not clear what is your question

Comment: example
item1 = 1pcs
item1 = 1pcs
, what i want to do
item1 = 2pcs

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the additional items to the `SubItems` collection of your `ListViewItem`.  Also, you should set the `View` property of the `ListView` to *Details* and add columns to the `Columns` collection

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    price = 500;
    quantity = Double.Parse(maskedTextBox1.Text);
    total = price * quantity;

    //The 4 lines below should only be executed one time and not every time
    //you press the button.  It was added here for illustrative purposes only.  Try adding them to the `OnLoad` method.

    this.listView1.View = View.Details;
    this.listView1.Columns.Add("Name", 100);
    this.listView1.Columns.Add("Total", 100);
    this.listView1.Columns.Add("Quantity", 100);

    //Move the above 4 lines to the `OnLoad` method.

    var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(form1.label1.Text);
    listViewItem.SubItems.Add(total.ToString());
    listViewItem.SubItems.Add(quantity.ToString());

    form1.listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);
}
```

Comment: thanks, i already set the ListView to Details, but my problem is that whenever i click "button1" it duplicates the Item what i want is to just add the quantity number on the same item

Comment: @Ixion - To update, you would need to first get the item that you wanted to update and then set the `SubItem.Text` property to the new value.  To change the quantity, it would be something like this:  `this.listView1.Items[0].SubItems[2].Text = newquantity.ToString();`   where 0 is the row number in the `ListView` and 2 is the column number.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using this:

```
ListViewItem item = listView1.FindItemWithText("itemSample");
```